# Printing feature and sdk installation intigrating with JAVA android in Ingenico APOS A8

Tags: java, android, sdk, pos

I have developed a POS (Point of sale system) in java (GUI based) in which I want to manage card swiping, payment, and ticket printing and I am looking for confirmation if Ingenico SDK as being integrated with java will be supported in these Ingenico devices (Ingenico APOS A8 models).  I need guidelines and SDKs and jar files related to integrating an application.